# List Error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arraylist

Error was found in Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + list[i]);
It says System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException I dont get the problem since VS doesnt underlines anything.

Sorry for dumb question, im just started my c# study.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wbs
{
    class Programm
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (a == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Falsche eingabe.");
            }
            else
            {
                List<long> list = new List<long>();
                long n = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
                {
                    n *= i;
                    list.Add(n);
                    Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + list[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"what I dont understand is that I dont any INT declared"* -- Uhhhh... `int a = 0;`

Comment: Index of List should be an int (`i`)

Comment: but it have nothing to do the with list, i also had it as long and it was same error.

Comment: `but it have nothing to do the with list,` Then what is this line `List<long> list = new List<long>();` ?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance carefully and [edit] post to provide minimal sample (which in this case should be like `var first = (new List<long>{1})[(long)0];`...

Comment: Lioha, im learning C# for 2 days what do you expect from me?...

Answer (score 2):

The `list[]` indexer takes `int`, not `long`.

You should not use `long` here.

Comment: But it will save very long digits shouldnt I use better long for that?

Comment: Ive changed to INT and now I 2 Errors: Boths Variables n and i by the list-

Comment: list.Add(n);
                    Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + list[i]);

Comment: @eXme what you have to do is `for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)` . :))))

Comment: It doesn't matter what's stored *in* the list. The indexer is for determining *where* in the list.

Comment: @eXme Then you will have to switch to something else than `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, as it has a maximum size of `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: Im not that advanced, I just wanted to practive some LISTs and I had this error pumped up, so tryed everything I knew and now it says System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Its kind of hard to understand that advanced answer :)

Comment: @Ian: in his code example there can never be any need for a larger capacity than a List provides: the maximum number of iterations is an int.

Comment: @JohanDonne Yeah, assuming he would change the input from `int` to `long` aswell.

Comment: Ive read some tutorials and they used some other command for the list, it was like list.insert(1, "blabla"); or its kind of stone age old?

Comment: @Ian: Fair point, but I think calculating the factorial will result in an overflow of his 'long' value when he reaches the limit of the List capapcity. So at that point he not only needs another collection type, but  he should witch from long to something like BigInt.

Comment: @eXme: You're confusing the _values_ in the list (which are large and may need `long` or `BigInteger`) with the _indexes_ of the list (which will never be large).  Those should be different types; as long as you make your types consistent, you won't have any problems.

Comment: @JohanDonne At the moment there is no point in using the list anyways, as he doesn't reuse the list's data.

Comment: @eXme:  'Add' appends the new value at the end of the List, 'Insert' inserts it in the indicated position (moving the rest up a position).

Comment: I dont want to print high numbers, I just wanted to test it for 10 lines and thats all, and after I recived that error message. I cant go sleep now without the working code :)

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at my updated answer first: you may sleep better :).

Comment: @eXme: That's not what is in my update answer... (read the end of the explanantion).

Comment: Hi, it had nothing to do with datatypes :) it was simple logical mistake, took me whole day to find out lol how simple it was :D Ive tryed to output something that not even exist yet :D

Answer (score 0):

use the following in your 'else' body:

```
  List<long> list = new List<long>();
  long n = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
  {
     n *= i;
     list.Add(n);
     Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + list[i-1]);
   }
```

Note the 'long' in the List declararation & the 'int' in the for-loop.
Since you are limiting 'i' to 'a' int should be sufficiënt for i as well. On top of that, I don't think you will be calculating more than 2^31 factorials :).

Furthermore you had another error:

The initial value for 'i' is 1. So, after adding  just one value to the list, you are trying to read list[1]. But the list index is 0-based, so that should be list[0].
So in your code replace list[i] with list[i-1] as in the code above.

Comment: well I want just to do test calculation to practive with list and factorials. that the error what ive got by editing the code as you wrote, I had it already thats why I tho i should add long everywhere: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er darf nicht negativ und kleiner als die Sammlung sein."

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify which error you are (still) getting with the above code (certainly not the error you mentioned in your Original question?)

Comment: NOt its not the error from the original request im getting another now: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException "The index was out of the Range. He cant be negativ or smaller then the collection"

Comment: There was an additional error in your code (see updated answer)

Comment: Ive found the problem myself took me whole damn day :D and now I see your answer! God damn! Thank tho !:D

Comment: on the positive side: you certainly learned a bit in the process :)

Comment: Yeah of course that motivated me again to study c# more intense :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in this line:

> Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + list1[j++]);

there cant be any list with the adress of 1 as i was declated at the begining, the list same as arrays start from 0, so I tryed to start it from the 1 and that cause the out of range error :)

i was 1, but my list started from 0 not 1 :) took me whole damn day but i learned alot tho that.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wbs
{
    class Programm
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Falsche eingabe.");
            }
            else
            {
                List<double> list1 = new List<double>();
                double n = 1;

                for (int i = 1, j = 0; i <= a; i++)
                {
                    n = n * i;
                    list1.Add(n);
                    Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + list1[j++]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```